# How could I add restrictions or rules to a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, function

I'm doing a solitaire program, and it's meant to run in the Python shell instead of a GUI. But I'm not quite so sure how to program the cards so that a `Red Suit` can be appended onto a `Black Suit` and vice versa. Also, the number of the card that is to be appended has to be lower than card before it.

I suppose the program used to add restrictions to the row stacks could be similar to the program used to add restrictions to the suit stacks. If it's different, could you also give me some help on this? Because I've nearly finished the project, but I've just got to add rules.

I've tried to figure out how I could do it, but it seems quite complicated.

```
def check(card1,card2):
    valid = True
    cardSuit = Card1[1]
    cardVal  = card1[0]

    if cardSuit2 == cardSuit[1]:
        valid = False

    elif value(CardVal1) > value(cardVal2):
        valid = False

    elif valid == False:
       # print Error Message

    return valid

# Function to call above function
def call():
    ok = check(card1,card2)
    if ok = True:
        # proceed with code

def value(str):
              if val is (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10):
              denon = int(val)
              elif val = 'J':
              denon = 11
              elif val = 'Q':
              denon = 12
              elif val = 'K':
              denon = 13

    return denon
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code has lots of errors and antipatterns, you should first bring it to a point where the code you have at least works. Where is the problem and what is the question?

Comment: @JochenRitzel; I just need help with adding rules to a list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possiblity. It's not perfectly clean data-wise, but might give you an idea. However I suppose you better understand the example really well, before you copy. As mentioned it is quite a difference to your initial idea ;)

```
CARD_VALUES=["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
SUIT_COLOR={"clubs": "black", "spades":"black", "hearts":"red", "diamonds":"red"}


class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        if value not in CARD_VALUES:
            raise Exception("Invalid card value {}".format(value))

        if suit not in SUIT_COLOR:
            raise Exception("Invalid suit {}".format(suit))

        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def suit_color(self):
        return SUIT_COLOR[self.suit]

    def card_value(self):
        return CARD_VALUES.index(self.value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "({} of {})".format(self.value, self.suit)


class Row:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards=[]

    def valid_add_card(self, card):
        if not self.cards:
            return True # true for empty deck

        last_card=self.cards[-1]
        return last_card.card_value()==card.card_value()+1 and last_card.suit_color()!=card.suit_color()

    def add_card(self, card):
        if self.valid_add_card(card):
            self.cards.append(card)
        else:
            raise Exception("Cannot add card {} to {}".format(card, self.cards[-1]))

    def __repr__(self):
        return " - ".join(str(c) for c in self.cards)


r=Row()
r.add_card(Card("J", "spades"))
r.add_card(Card("10", "hearts"))
r.add_card(Card("9", "clubs"))
print(r)
print("Last card won't work:")
r.add_card(Card("8", "spades"))
```

Comment: Thanks, let me look through it.

Answer (score 3):

Subclass list and implement the functionality that you want.http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/ch03s02.html
 If you subclass Python List it comes with FREE built in functionality that would work perfect for solitare, `append` and `pop` you could implement your desired card checking then call the original List method.

Additionally I would make a `Card` object.  It might be easier to keep everything organized this way.   It could keep track of it's color, suite, human display(if it's a face card)